# Error "unterminated string literal" in jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I've got a very strange error, been trying for ages to find it out in this file:

http://4nf.org/js/GA.js

Maybe you can spot it at a glance - I seem to be blind at the moment...

Any help is greatly appreciated, cause I'm in real time trouble

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you get a line number with the error?

Comment: are you sure it's an error in this exact code? it seems everything is ok with it

Comment: Use the "Inspect Element" feature in Chrome to get a line number on the error.

Comment: where is GA.txt? can you provide the path of this file. As i checked, this file giving 404 error. which is resulting in your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your ajax response and the string coming from it you must use some kind of encoding to parse the ajax response.

Also try to debug it by removing one variable at one time for example

```
var v = getFileContents(settings['GACodePath']);
```

And change the value of v .Means i am trying to say that find the exact variable of due to which you are getting this error

Comment: That was it - the AJAX request failed and the web-server sent loads of rubbish!